# Can I use a cell containing a date to reference for multiple Pivot Tables in Excel?

Tags: excel, windows-7, excel-2007, office-2007

I am using Excel 2007 & about 20 pivot charts/graphs which reference the same table of data in Excel. I change the data daily, copy and pasting the data from another source. Can I somehow create a reference cell that contains a date for the pivot tables so that I don’t have to change the dates on every graph drop down every day? Another solution would be to have all the graphs reference the same data section on the pivot table, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

as far as the data range of a pivot table is concerned, you can base multiple Pivots on the same data range.

- define the 1st Pivot Table by selecting the data range
- for Pivot Tables 2..n select the 1st table as the data source

for Pivot charts - if you just want to display the actual date in a title

- create the Pivot Chart
- click the title and enter a formula making use of your "dynamic title cell" in same way as in sheets (e.g. `=Sheet1!$A$1`)
- at least in Excel 2003 it's not possible to do this in a Pivot Chart Title: `="Stat for " & Sheet1!$A$1`; so as a workaround you do this in cell A1 of Sheet1